# Viewing parallel edges with Arango's web interface graph viewer?

Tags: arangodb

Let's say I have two vertexes, Cameron and Jerry. Cameron has three edges that go to Jerry, the edges are of different collections. Arango's web viewer does not seem to be able show this even if the edge collections are set as part of the graph. Arango's graph viewer seems to only be able to show one single edge between any two vertices. Is a fix on the feature roadmap?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the ArangoDB webinterface uses [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) for visualizing graphs.

In the graph viewer you can click on the burger-menu in the upper right, where you have the possibility to switch the `Edges`-Type to `Curve` - in which case you will see more than one connection between two vertices.

If you need more versatile graphical graph exploration, you can use [ArangoExport](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Programs/Arangoexport/) to generate intermediate [GML files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Modelling_Language) that can in term be opened in [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/).